# Should my edit and new actions re-use the same view? (editing a post)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this setup in my routes:

```
namespace :admin do
     resources :posts

  end
```

so in my admin/posts_controller.rb I have my new, create and edit actions.

I want to re-use my new and edit view page somehow, b/c the page has allot of custom javascript etc. for the form and I don't want to repeat myself.

How can I do this?

i.e. for the edit page, I have to pre-populate the form fields and for the new page it is to be empty.

For a new page, it should post to the 'create' action, and for the edit I am thinking it should post to a different 'update' action (which is a PUT request as per my rake routes)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails is pretty clever, a form like

```
<% form_for post do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

will post to the create action if `post.new_record? == true` and to the update action otherwise.

So, you can put the form in a partial, and render it inside your new/edit views, which will probably have different headings and copy.

Alternatively you can just have a single view and perform your own logic based on `post.new_record?` - but I'd advise against this because you'll end up with an unnecessarily complex view.